# graphics.sty - File 'pdftex.def' not found

Tags: graphics, pdftex

After updating MikTeX today, I get the error

```
graphics.sty - line 100 - File 'pdftex.def' not found
```

I've reduced the document to the following and still get the error.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I've found the missing document here (as part of a bundle): [pdftex.def](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdftex-def?lang=en). But I have no idea, where to put the pdftex.def file or what else I could do to resolve this error.

I work on Win 10, with MikTeX 2.9, TeXstudio 2.11.0.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Some packages have been rearrange. You should synchronize your offline package list and then if needed install graphics-def, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108490/2388

Comment: I solve this problem with install `graphics-def`.

Comment: Thank you, @UlrikeFischer, synchronizing according to the link provided solved the issue.

Comment: Installing `graphics-def` fixed the problem for me too! Thanks @Zarko

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, but with a TeXLive 2016 distribution. Perhaps a broken update. I installed `graphics-def` but it did not solve the problem. However, **rebuilding all formats using `tlmgr`** solved the problem. Hope it helps!

Comment: This is unlikely to help a user of MikTeX. `tlmgr` is, after all, the TeX Live package manager, but isn't it?

Comment: True, but rebuilding formats / refreshing the filename database in MikTeX might help. That was my intention...

Comment: the question's keywords are ``graphics`` and ``pdftex`` _NOT_ ``MikTeX`` and the error message occurs with ``TeXlive`` too, so IMHO this answer is appropriate here.

Comment: Also, does not help anyone running TeXLive on platforms other than Windows...

Answer (score 1):

Also had the same issue on Windows 7.
For me the solution was to **first synchronize** the package database in MiKTeX:

run `\MiKTeX 2.9\Maintenance (Admin)\Package Manager (Admin)`

In the menu, go to `Repository > Synchronize`
[image: MiKTeX Package Manager (Admin) Menu]

**After that, update the packages** using:

run `\MiKTeX 2.9\Maintenance (Admin)\Update (Admin)`

Get the packages from a remote repository (you might have to select a mirror)
[image: MiKTeX Update (Admin) Menu]

In the next step, select **all** the packages and **update** them.