# Aberrant capitalization from Biber for Mac Tex Live not reproducible on other OS

Tags: biblatex, biber, capitalization

I have an article I have been writing with TeX Live on Ubuntu, but a change in circumstances has forced me to finish it on a Mac. Weirdly, the behavior of the bibliography is now very different. It insists on rendering article titles in German in ALL CAPS and in decapitalizing journal titles (i.e., "Tôhoku math. j. (2)," which is an abomination). What is causing this behavior? What can I do to overcome it?

[update: the promised MWE:

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !BIB program = biber
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee-alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibshort.bib}\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\cite{hopf1941hopf}\cite{BV1982}.
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

]

Comment: Mhh Biber should not do such a thing. It could be that something in your document produces this weird output, but it is unlikely. We really need an MWE. Do you get any errors or warnings in the `.log` or `.blg` file?

Comment: Still cutting down the MWE. Here's blg: https://pastebin.com/LfrGS6dp

Comment: Biber 2.4 is a bit outdated. The current version is 2.7. Other than that the `.blg` looks innocent enough.

Comment: log: https://pastebin.com/GbJTCNRX

Comment: Your `biblatex` and especially `biblatex-ieee` are also outdated. `biblatex-ieee` does some changes to capitalisation, I'm not sure if the old version you use had a bug related to that.

Comment: Added MWE. How to update?

Comment: It would be brilliant to see the `.bib` entries as well as the output. You can update MacTeX with `tlmgr`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864

Comment: Here are the two bib entries: https://pastebin.com/AgJdLmsR . I'll start trying to update this thing.

Comment: Try `Title = {Classes caract{\'e}ristiques {\'e}quivariantes. {Formule} de localisation en cohomologie {\'e}quivariante},` and `Title = {{\"U}ber eie {Topologie} der {Gruppen-Mannigfaltigkeiten} und ihre {Verallgemeinerungen}},` (BTW: Check the spelling of the last title, it's probably 'eine', not 'eie').

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the problem. It is due to excessive bracing interfering with the macro for capitalisation. You'll want

```
title = {Classes caract{\'e}ristiques {\'e}quivariantes. {Formule} de localisation en cohomologie {\'e}quivariante},
```

and

```
title = {{\"U}ber eine {Topologie} der {Gruppen-Mannigfaltigkeiten} und ihre {Verallgemeinerungen}},
```

Comment: Removing the spurious braces fixes the extra caps in Hopf's title, but still this does nothing for the capitalization of the journal names. How do they render for you?

Comment: @jdc Just fine as 'Ann. of Math.' Did one of the journals of the MWE cause trouble for you?

Comment: Both! They render, weirdly, as "C. r. acad. sci. paris, and "Ann. of math., Second Series."

Comment: @jdc Mhhh, as I said you have an older version of the package.

Comment: tlmgr needed to update itself, and now is starting to update 684 other things. Let us see...

Comment: @jdc Yes, let's. You could try `\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{#1}`, but that is a mere hunch.

Comment: The `sudo tlmgr update --all` has been failing because I've been trapped at airports with intermittent, slow wifi for about a day now. It finally completed, but I worried it because of the interruptions, it broke something: when I try to compile it says `pdftex.def not found`. As for that \DeclareFieldFormat, that seems somewhat post hoc, no? The system should not need that kind of manual interference if it's working right, right?

Comment: @jdc No idea about your missing `pdftex.def`. Maybe you can try again or see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/318453/35864 (in German, sorry: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/19297/tex-live-2016-file-pdftexdef-not-found). Of course the `\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{#1}` is ad hoc, it fixes a problem (or at least I hope it does) that is solved in the current version of the package. That was only meant to be a temporary solution in case you did not want to or could not update.

Comment: :Aha, I saw it too late. :/ The `pdftex.def` problem is persistent so I guess I'll try to fix that now. Thank you for all this help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59008/discussion-between-jdc-and-moewe).